# Can I add a field with Calendar content type on SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to make a list in SharePoint 2010 and add a SharePint Calendar field to this list. is it possible? if it is possible How can I have a sharepoint list with a field to store a calendar on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a date column to the custom list and then create a "Calendar View" for the custom list and config the view as you need.